# Sublime Text 2 on before modified?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

when i wrote code plugin for Sublime Text 2, i want to use event **on_before_modified**. But in [api page](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) (only on_modified), i not see that event, how i can do that?

Comment: Have you asked on the Sublime Text forums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `on_before_modified` event handler; however, you can use `on_query_context` to do the same thing.  It's a bit more complicated but it does get called before anything is modified.